# Golang (Go) AES CBC ciphertext gets padded with 16 0x00 bytes for some reason

Tags: go, encryption, aes

I am testing out the AES 256 CBC implementation in Golang (Go).

```
plaintext: {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Because the plaintext is 36 B and needs to be a multiple of the block size (16 B) I pad it manually with 12 random bytes to 48 B.
I understand that this is not the most secure way of doing it, but I am just testing, I will find a better way for production setups.

Inputs:

```
plaintext: aaaaaaaaaaaa{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
AES 256 key: b8ae2fe8669c0401fb289e6ab6247924
AES IV: e0332fc2a9743e4f
```

The code excerpt extracted, but modified a bit, from [here](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher@go1.18.3#NewCBCEncrypter):

```
block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error creating a new AES cipher by using your key!");
    fmt.Println(err);
    os.Exit(1);
}

ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))

mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, plaintext)

fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext)
fmt.Println("len(ciphertext):",len(ciphertext))
```

CipherText = PlainText + Block - (PlainText MOD Block)

This equation gives the length of the ciphertext for CBC.

So, the line `ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))` satisfies this requirement since my plaintext is always padded to be a multiple of the block size.

**Problem:**

With Go I get the following ciphertext:
`caf8fe667f4087e1b67d8c9c57fcb1f56b368cafb4bfecbda1e481661ab7b93d87703fb140368d3034d5187c53861c7400000000000000000000000000000000`

I always get 16 0x00 bytes at the end of my ciphertext, no matter the length of my plaintext.

If i do the same with an online AES calculator I get this ciphertext:
`caf8fe667f4087e1b67d8c9c57fcb1f56b368cafb4bfecbda1e481661ab7b93d87703fb140368d3034d5187c53861c74ccd202bac41937be75731f23796f1516`

The first 48 bytes `caf8fe667f4087e1b67d8c9c57fcb1f56b368cafb4bfecbda1e481661ab7b93d87703fb140368d3034d5187c53861c74` are the same. But I am missing the last 16 bytes.

[This](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher@go1.18.3#BlockMode) says:

> It is acceptable to pass a dst bigger than src, and in that case,
> CryptBlocks will only update dst[:len(src)] and will not touch the
> rest of dst.

But why is this the case ? The length of the ciphertext needs to be longer than the length of the plaintext and the online AES calculators prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ciphertext of the online tool results, if the plaintext:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

is padded with PKCS#7 and the posted key and IV are UTF8 encoded. Since the size of the plaintext (48 bytes) is already an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes for AES), a full block is padded according to the rules of [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7), resulting in a 64 bytes plaintext and ciphertext.

It is not clear from the question which online tool was used, but the posted ciphertext can be reconstructed with any reliable encryption tool, e.g. CyberChef, s. [this online calcualtion](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%27b8ae2fe8669c0401fb289e6ab6247924%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%27e0332fc2a9743e4f%27%7D,%27CBC%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFheyJrZXkxIjogInZhbHVlMSIsICJrZXkyIjogInZhbHVlMiJ9). CyberChef applies PKCS#7 padding for AES/CBC by default.

---

The posted code produces a different ciphertext because:

1. no PKCS#7 padding is applied. This makes the ciphertext one block shorter (i.e. the last block *ccd202bac41937be75731f23796f1516* is missing).
2. a size of `aes.BlockSize + len(plaintext)` bytes is allocated for the ciphertext. This causes the allocated size to be too large by `aes.BlockSize` bytes (i.e. the ciphertext contains 16 0x00 values at the end).

Therefore, for the Go code to produce the same ciphertext as the online tool, 1. the PKCS#7 padding must be added and 2. a size of only `len(plaintext)` bytes must be allocated for the ciphertext.

The following code is a possible implementation (for PKCS#7 padding [pkcs7pad](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zenazn/pkcs7pad) is used):

```golang
import (
    ...
    "github.com/zenazn/pkcs7pad"
)
...
key := []byte("b8ae2fe8669c0401fb289e6ab6247924")
iv := []byte("e0332fc2a9743e4f")
plaintext := []byte("aaaaaaaaaaaa{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}")
plaintext = pkcs7pad.Pad(plaintext, aes.BlockSize)  // 1. pad the plaintext with PKCS#7
block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ciphertext := make([]byte, len(plaintext))          // 2. allocate len(plaintext)
mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, plaintext)
fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext) // caf8fe667f4087e1b67d8c9c57fcb1f56b368cafb4bfecbda1e481661ab7b93d87703fb140368d3034d5187c53861c74ccd202bac41937be75731f23796f1516
```

Note that because of the PKCS#7 padding, explicit padding with `a` is no longer required.

---

The *static* IV used in the above code is a vulnerability as it leads to reuse of key/IV pairs, which is insecure. In practice, therefore, a random IV is usually generated for each encryption. The IV is not secret, is needed for decryption, and is typically concatenated with the ciphertext. On the decryption side, IV and ciphertext are separated and used for decryption.
Since the size of the IV corresponds to the blocksize, a size of `aes.BlockSize + len(plaintext)` must be allocated for the ciphertext, which is equal to the size in the original code. Possibly this is not accidental and was designed with a random IV in mind, but then not implemented consequently. A consequent implementation is:

```golang
import (
    ...
    "crypto/rand"
    "io"
    "github.com/zenazn/pkcs7pad"
)
...
key := []byte("b8ae2fe8669c0401fb289e6ab6247924")
plaintext := []byte("{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}")
plaintext = pkcs7pad.Pad(plaintext, aes.BlockSize)
block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]        
_, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv)   // create a random IV
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)
fmt.Printf("%x\n", ciphertext)
```

The first 16 bytes of the output correspond to the (random) IV and the rest to the actual ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I will review this and experiment some more with the PKCS#7 padding.